# What is the difference between OpenFDA's Drug Label API and DailyMed?

Tags: openfda, drugs

I am interested in downloading and processing structured product label (SPL) data. What is the difference between DailyMed API and OpenFDA's (https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/label/) API?

Is one more robust? Does one have a better format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DailyMed SPL API ([example](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v2/spls/1efe378e-fee1-4ae9-8ea5-0fe2265fe2d8.xml)) returns the actual SPL XML file while openFDA API ([example](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=set_id:1efe378e-fee1-4ae9-8ea5-0fe2265fe2d8)) returns a JSON document containing information parsed out of SPL along with annotations added via the `openfda` element. The choice between the two really depends on the needs specific to your project.

Since you mentioned "downloading and processing", please note that you can download all the drug labels in SPL format "in bulk" [here](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/spl-resources-all-drug-labels.cfm) for further processing on your end *or* you can download openFDA JSON [drug label data](https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/label/download/) in bulk as well.